# Unable to Print ANSI Escape codes in Simply Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I have been trying to use ANSI escape codes to clear the screen in simply scheme, but when I do so it either does not work and returns:

> `read-syntax: missing ']' to close preceding '[', found instead ')'`

when trying `(display '\033[2J)`

Or when turning it into a string it prints out (in purple for some reason, even though it is the clear screen code)

> `[2J`

when doing `(display "\033[2J")`

I have been stuck here for a while as `(clear)` does not work in Simply Scheme, and doing `'\033\[2J` only causes a different error. All help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using DrRacket? ANSI code doesn't work in DrRacket. It does work when you run a Racket file in command-line, though. Try running `racket` in command-line and enter `(display "\033[2J")`. It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interacting with Racket using DrRacket then ANSI escape codes won't work.  If you are running Racket in a terminal which supports them, they will.  There may be a way of erasing a buffer in DrRacket programmatically, but it's not this.

Comment: Well, guess I cant do it then